# An identity for symmetric multilinear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, multilinear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following identity for symmetric multilinear functions. Let $V,W$ be vector spaces, and let $F : V^k \to W$ be $k$-linear and symmetric. Let $x,y \in V$, and suppose $x_0,x_1,...,x_N \in V$ are such that $x_0 = x, x_N = y$. I would like to know if
$${1 \over k!} F[(y-x)^k] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sum\limits_{j=1}^k {1 \over j! (k-j)!} F[(x_{i-1}-x)^{k-j}(x_i-x_{i-1})^j].$$
In the case $k=1$, this is straightforward. In the case $k=2$, the right hand side is
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N F[(x_{i-1}-x)(x_i - x_{i-1})] + {1 \over 2} F[(x_i - x_{i-1})^2] $$
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} F[(x_j - x_{j-1})(x_i - x_{i-1})]) + {1 \over 2} F[(x_i - x_{i-1})^2]$$
$$= \sum\limits_{i=1}^N ({1 \over 2} \sum\limits_{j \neq i} F[(x_j - x_{j-1})(x_i - x_{i-1})]) + {1 \over 2} F[(x_i - x_{i-1})^2]$$
$$= {1 \over 2} F[(y-x)^2].$$
Is there some straightforward argument for the general case?

**Edit**: I forgot that I want $F$ to be symmetric.

Comment: Does $F[(x-y)^k]$ mean $F(x-y, \cdots, x-y)$ in the standard functional notation, as I suspect?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: And do you mean $x_0$ instead of $x$ in on the LHS of the thesis?

Comment: Ah, I meant to include that $x_0 = x, x_N = y$.

Comment: Still, when $i=1$ you have $(x_0-x_0) = 0$ in the first $k-j$ slots, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint toward the complete argument. Notice that the symmetry of $F$ implies that we can freely exchange two arguments without any difference in the outcome:
$$F(b,b,\dots,A,\dots,b) = F(A,b,\dots,b,\dots,b)$$
so that the sum
$$F(A,b,\dots,b,\dots,b) + F(b,A,\dots,b,\dots,b) + \cdots + F(b,b,\dots,A,\dots,b) + \cdots + F(b,b,\dots,b,\dots,A) $$
becomes
$$k\cdot F(A,b,\dots,b,\dots,b) $$
and similarly the sum of all $F(b,\dots,A,\dots,A,\dots,b)$ over all possible changes in the order of the arguments amounts to
$$\binom{k}{2} \cdot F(A,A,\dots,b) $$
So we have some combinatorial action going on. If we sum over all possible choices of how many $A$'s we feed into $F$, we have (in your notation)
$$\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j} F[A^j b^{k-j}] $$
Does this make things clearer to you?